# How to make an if argument on several inputs together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to make an if argument that will check if several inputs(that have the same class) have a value of negative number on several.
If one of them have, I want to have an error message.
I have been trying to do so, and I got the error message that I wanted but it continues to the next step eventhough I wrote return and event.preventDefault.
[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zj7y8tqm/)

My code below:

```
$("#inventoryForm").submit(function (event) {
          $(".inventoryInput").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() < 0) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#inventoryError").slideDown().text("blablabla");
            ;
            return;
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: it should be return false if i m not mistaken

Comment: Didn't work. Anyway, I don't think it matters if I return false or none..

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle demo for this code with html

Comment: @imbondbaby  you are right. If the callback function of jquery.each() returns false the iteration will be ended.

Comment: I edited and added my fiddle. I've been trying with the return false but with no success.

Comment: In `jQuery.each`, `return` is like `continue` and `return false` is like `break`

Comment: Is this, by any chance an asp.net application?  Or are there multiple submit handlers?

Comment: I tried your fiddle and it worked well. I added a positive number in the first field followed by two fields with  negative numbers then a positive number. I got one message "blabla". I think that's correct. Isn't it?

Comment: Peter, it did give you the message but it continued the function of the button anyway. That is what I wanted to happen. You can see that right way below in plalx solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the rest of your code. `event.preventDefault()` will not return out of the submit handler, it will just prevent the default form submit behavior.

Here's what you can do:

```
$("#inventoryForm").submit(function (event) {
       var error = false;

       //You seem to always want to prevent the default behavior
       event.preventDefault();

          $(".inventoryInput").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() < 0) {

                error = true; //Indicate there was an error
                $("#inventoryError").slideDown().text("blablabla");
                return false; //This stops the iteration
            }

        });

        //Stop processing if there was an error
        if (error) return;

        $("#inventorySubmit").hide();
        $("#inventoryChange").show();
        $("#withdraw").show();
        $(".inventoryInput").attr('disabled','disabled');
        sum = 0;
         /* var money = table.find("td:nth-child(2)");
        for (var i = 0; i<money.length; i++) {

        }
        */
    });
```

Btw the code is even more consise without jQuery:

```
var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.inventoryInput'));

if (inputs.some(haveValueUnderZero)) {
    //error
}

function haveValueUnderZero(input) { return input.value < 0; }
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you! Just a question, Why do I need to do a if argument outside the function instead of returning false and that's it?

Comment: @ronilitman Your `return false` is inside the `.each` callback function. Therefore, you only return out of that function and stop the iteration, but the control returns to the submit callback function. You have to return early out of that function too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#inventoryForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".inventoryInput").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() < 0) {
            $("#inventoryError").slideDown().text("blablabla");
            return false;
        } else {
            $("#inventorySubmit").hide();
            $("#withdraw").show();
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Also, you need to insert other functions like `$("#withdraw").show();` inside the `else` statement.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zj7y8tqm/3/)**

Comment: @ronilitman because you need to put the other show, hide functions inside the else statement

Comment: I have checked. The problem is that the submit button still works. You can see that because the disabled input. So in that way we didn't stop it from working, just hidden it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
      $(".inventoryInput").each(function(){
             var el = $(this)
            $("#inventoryForm").on("submit", function (event) {
            if(el.val() < 0) {

                $("#inventoryError").slideDown().text("blablabla");
                return false;
        }

    })
});
```

Comment: Still won't work.. Can you make it on my fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

try a hidden verify function:

```js
window.verify = function() {
  var valid = true;
  $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() < 0) {
      valid = false;
    }
  });
  if (valid) {
    $('#submit').click();
  } else {
    alert("Please complete all fields.");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="inventoryForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Product Id" name="prod_id" id="prod_id" />
  <input type="number" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity" id="quantity" />
  <button type="button" onclick="verify()">Submit</button>
  <button id="submit" type="submit" style="display:none"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `filter` function to return only elements that do not match your condition.

```
var hasErrorElements = $('.inventoryInput').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).val()) < 0;
}).length > 0;

if (hasErrorElements) {
    alert('Error!');
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```